How do I programmatically update current flutter app from server?

Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.example.app.provider/... typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive flg=0x50000001 pkg=com.example.app }


MainActivity.kt
UpdateService.kt
AndroidManifest

I want to programmatically download apk from server if there is the latest version of it and download app in the background and upon completing close current running app and update to the new version of it by installing currently downloaded APK
Flutter version

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

I'd think this is up to the user.  I know I can choose to "auto update" on ios, and when my phone is idle, it sees if there are updates in the store and downloads those for me.  To have an app modify itself would be a violation of the rules of the stores, I would think.
